# Pycharm & plotly: fig.show() does not work in console mode

Tags: python, console, plotly

I am relatively new to Python & worked with plotly mainly in R. However, I managed to conduct a correct figure which is working fine when using the "Run" command. However, if I try to to this via the console it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

fig = px.scatter(
    pd.DataFrame({"X": [1, 2, 3], "Y": [3, 2, 1]}),
    x="X",
    y="Y"
)

fig.show()
```

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2022.1

Thank you!

Comment: I found out, that it works if I change the interpreter von Conda to Python.. but I'd like to use Conda b/c of magic. Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Do you get a specific error message when you run this via Conda?

Comment: @kͩeͣmͮpͥͩ No, it does not show any error. It just don't open the browser to view the plot

Comment: You probably need to read the documentation at https://plotly.com/python/renderers/ to understand this.
I'd imagine Conda is doing something to your `path` that stops the browser opening